# UITextField keyboard dosen't work any more

Tags: xcode, keyboard

Please need help : I have two textfield in a view , save button and done button. now first time when I run my app, and type in a textfield the keyboard apperas good and I can save. but when I press done button to exit that view , the keyboard don't appears any more in any other part in my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just a shot in the dark here, but try to use

```
[textField resignFirstResponder];
```

in the done action

Comment: i Fixed more simple: i put the same button(save) two funcion (save + done) and is work perfect. thank